# Water Leaks under faucet (only when cleaning faucet)

Tags: leak, faucet, mold

water is dripping down my faucet as seen/highlighted red in the picture, only when I am pouring water over faucet to clean it up. The blue highlighted part is where I used to spray with spray bottle to clean the mold (lack of better word). Please let me know how can I fix this nuisance.

[image]

Comment: I would drizzle clear Elmer's glue in there, maybe watered down so it penetrates. A few daily applications and it should dry and fill the void w/o fogging (don't use superglue) or making a permanent modification to the sink.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a gasket/putty/caulking under the faucet.

Remove the faucet, clean all old sealing, and replace the sealing or use a sponge to wipe the top down instead of water/spray.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am a very newbie. Any idea which sealing to use, and clean and replace?

Comment: @programmerboy   If not a gasket, then plumbers putty or silicon caulk will work.  A cheap(labour) fast hack would be to just clean the bottom of the joint of the faucet and sink, and use some silicon caulk along the edge.

Comment: do you mean to say, lift the faucet from the blue area by unscrewing from bottom (red area), apply the caulk around the holes, and put the faucet back on?

Comment: @programmerboy  Caulking/sealing goes between the outside edge of faucet base and top of the sink.  The outside edge will then sit on the caulking and squeezing the caulking down onto the sink top.